# Symfony yml parameters into doctrine yml mapping

Tags: symfony, doctrine, mapping, yaml

I have a question regarding doctrine yml file. Is it possible to import a yml configuration file, such as parameters.yml and to use those parameters into the mapping configuration ?

For example here is what I would like to do:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
Yunai39\Bundle\SimpleLdapBundle\Entity\RoleLdap:
    type: entity

    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        roleName:
            type: string
            length: '255'
    manyToMany:
        users:
            targetEntity: "%user_class%"
            mappedBy: roles
```

Does anyone know if that is possible ?

Comment: There is no import in YAML, if it can be done it is something that symfony2 does with the data it reads in from YAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.

However, it looks like [Resolving Target Entities](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html) is something you might be interested in, as it looks like you're trying to do exactly that.

> Doctrine 2.2 includes a new utility called the ResolveTargetEntityListener, that functions by intercepting certain calls inside Doctrine and rewriting targetEntity parameters in your metadata mapping at runtime. It means that in your bundle you are able to use an interface or abstract class in your mappings and expect correct mapping to a concrete entity at runtime.

Comment: Thanks so much !! This seems to be exactly what I want, I could not figure how FOS was doing it, thanks so much, I will tell you if I have any problem but seems like I should be able to do it, thx again